# Textfield deleting newly added characters

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a `label` that gets info from the previous `view controller` as follows

```
  @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
   var label = String()

  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.textField.text = String(self.label.dropLast())
    }
```

Here is the scenario:

```
textField on loading: Apple (edit Icon)
textField on editing first time: Apples are healthy
textField on tapping again: Apple
```

Everything is fine when I start editing `textField` but once I tapped outside or go to another field and come back to the `textField`, all the editing is gone. How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Have you added any other textfield delegate methods?

Comment: Only, textFieldDidEndEditing for sake of tint color.

Comment: Can you give an example with actual strings of what's happening?

Comment: check the `clear when editing begins` property in storyboard if it's marked or not

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly, i.e. using _textField's_ delegate?

Comment: The only reason I used delegates is for adding edit icon, which will be deleted on tap and I can edit.

Comment: @TMob, please see the edited post

Comment: Well every time you enter the text-field it will set its content to the content of "label" with one character removed. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to keep my edit without being reset. I cannot think of any way to do it. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I mean what are you trying to achieve with setting the text of the textfield to label.dropLast? Do you want to fill it with the value of a previous viewController?

Comment: so you want to show/hide edit icon depending on whether the textField is first responder or not?

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi Exactly, that is what I want to do and I don't know whether I am using the right delegate

Comment: @TMob, Yes I want to fill it with value of previous viewController with edit icon and remove that edit icon, when tapped on this new ViewController.

Comment: Okay, so, is there a _single textField_ in your ViewController or is there a tableView with each cell having their own _textFields_ (like you are resting the same cell for the tableView)

Comment: Only single textField and I don't have any tableView

Comment: Then you can just toggle the visibility of the _edit icon_ using `isHidden` property inside `textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)` and `textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextField.DidEndEditingReason)`

Comment: But why are you using this `self.textField.text = String(self.label.dropLast())` , I still wonder if you just want to toggle the visibility of the edit icon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190288/discussion-between-coder221-and-shubham-bakshi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because `textFieldDidBeginEditing` is called each time you tap on the textField, so the text is reset to your label's text.

If it is a one-time-only assignment, you should consider doing it in `viewDidLoad`. This will also allow you to keep your initial label value if you don't want it changed.

You can also assign the text to your label property in `textFieldDidEndEditing`.

Comment: Could you explain why not? Something like `label = textField.text ?? ""` in `textFieldDidEndEditing` should do the work.

Comment: I did understand what you are telling lately. This does work :)

Comment: Glad I could help :) Best of luck!